# Can we create a singleton bean of a list of strings in a micronaut application?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, factory, micronaut, inject

I have been trying to inject this bean (below) and have created it in a @Factory class.

```
@Bean
@Singleton
@Named("dependencyPackagesBean")
List<String> provideDependencyPackages(Config config) {
    List<String> dependencies = new ArrayList<>();
    dependencies.addAll(DEPENDENCY_PACKAGES);
    dependencies.addAll(config.getDependencyPackagesOverrides());
    return dependencies;
}
```

And injecting it in a class as such:

```
@Inject
public JobManager(@Named("dependencyPackagesBean") List<String> dependencyPackages,
                  Instrumentation instrumentation) {
    this.dependencyPackages = dependencyPackages;
    this.instrumentation = instrumentation;
}
```

However, upon running the application, I see that everytime, an empty list gets injected.
`DEPENDENCY_PACKAGES` is defined as:

```java
public static final List<String> DEPENDENCY_PACKAGES = List.of("com.stuff");
```

Is it not possible to inject List as a named bean, the way I have done it? If so, what is wrong with the way I have tried to inject it?

Using a wrapper class that contains the list I am trying to inject, creating a bean for that wrapper class and injecting and then using that injected object to fetch the list works. But wanted to understand what is wrong if I don't use a wrapper class and try to inject a named bean of a list of strings directly.

Comment: Have you tried to qualify your list bean using an custom annotation instead the name? https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#qualifiers